# Error to pass to PHP Papa Parse object using AJAX

Tags: javascript, php, ajax, papaparse

I would like to extract a CSV local file in PHP using AJAX.
To do that I tried to use Papa Parse and it works great. The problem is to pass the results with AJAX. I tried with JSON.stringify, I tried to pass only the first field; I tried also to create a JSON object and then add the results to this object but, I don't know why, when I extract in PHP I got only the values of the original object.

```
values = {};
values['row_1'] = 'value1';
values['row_2'] = 'value2';
i = 3
$("input[type=file]").parse({
    config: {
        delimiter: ",",
        step: function(results) {
            value = results.data[0]
            values['row_' + i] = value 
            i = i + 1
        }
    }
});

$.ajax({
  type: "POST",
  url: "extract-csv.php",
  data: {
    id: $('#id').val(),
    ...
    values: values
  }
...
})
```

With this code on PHP I returned only "value1" and "value2" (if I print "values" in the console I get object with 2++ elements)

Answer (score 0):

Papa Parse worked after Ajax, so the solution is to put the Ajax call in the "Complete" Papa Parse function and then everything works fine!